# Converting NFA to DFA

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Im trying to convert a NFA to DFA.

This is the NFA

[image]

and this is the DFA to which i converted

[image]

Is this right?

Also when converting if i write a state as [q0,q1] is this same as [q1,q0]

edit:

Im calculating the DFA as follows

step 1:

[image]

step 2:

[image]

step 3:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Your second picture does not show a DFA: there is no $0$-transition from $\{q_1\}$, and there are no transitions at all from $\{q_2\}$.

Comment: After writing down the states Q1 does not have 0 Transitions and q2  does not have any transitions This is the Technique i followed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMfLTfoJUAI

Comment: The explanation in that video is not very good. In particular, he got a state $\varnothing$, but then he failed to incorporate it into his DFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The states of your DFA are the $8$ subsets of $\{q_0,q_1,q_2\}$, though you may not actually need all of them. Your initial state will be the set of all initial states of the NFA; this appears to be the set $\{q_0\}$. In the NFA there are $0$-transitions from $q_0$ to both $q_0$ and $q_1$, so the DFA will have a transition $$\{q_0\}\overset{0}\longrightarrow\{q_0,q_1\}\;.$$ The NFA has no $1$-transition from $q_0$, so the $1$ transition from $\{q_0\}$ in the DFA must be to $\varnothing$, the empty set of states: $$\{q_0\}\overset{1}\longrightarrow\varnothing\;.$$

In the NFA the $0$-transitions from $q_0$ are to $q_0$ and $q_1$, and there are no $0$-transitions from $q_1$, so the $0$-transition from $\{q_0,q_1\}$ in the DFA is a loop back to $\{q_0,q_1\}$: $$\{q_0,q_1\}\overset{0}\longrightarrow\{q_0,q_1\}\;.$$ In the NFA the only $1$-transition out of $q_0$ or $q_1$ goes to $q_2$, so the DFA must have the $1$-transition $$\{q_0,q_1\}\overset{1}\longrightarrow\{q_2\}\;.$$

The NFA has no transitions from $q_2$, so in the DFA both the $0$- and the $1$-transition from $\{q_2\}$ must go to $\varnothing$: $$\{q_2\}\overset{0,1}\longrightarrow\varnothing\;.$$

Finally, the NFA obviously has no transitions that start nowhere, so in the DFA both transitions from $\varnothing$ must loop back to $\varnothing$: $$\varnothing\overset{0,1}\longrightarrow\varnothing\;.$$

The only acceptor state in the NFA is $q_2$, and the only state in the DFA that contains $q_2$ is $\{q_2\}$, so the only acceptor state in the DFA is $\{q_2\}$.

None of the other four potential states of the DFA ($\{q_1\},\{q_0,q_2\},\{q_1,q_2\},\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$) is accessible from the initial state $\{q_0\}$, so there’s no need to work out the transitions involving them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I have worked out in a similar fashion.Please tell me what im doing wrong.I have updated the question

Comment: @techno: You’re making the same mistake that he made in the video: your transition table clearly shows a state $\varnothing$, but it doesn’t appear in your digraph. A DFA with input alphabet $\{0,1\}$ must have both a $0$-transition and a $1$-transition out of **every** state; what you’ve drawn is missing all of the transitions that should go to state $\varnothing$. Also, you haven’t filled in a row of the transition table for the state $\varnothing$; both transitions from it should go to $\varnothing$, as in the last displayed line of my answer.

Comment: Thanks.So i should add state ∅ to the transition diagram to the solve the issue right?

Comment: @techno: Yes, with the transitions into and out of it that I listed in my answer. You’re welcome.

Comment: Please see the Update.I have done as you have said

Comment: @techno: You need to label the $1$-transition from $\{q_2\}$ to $\varnothing$, but otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Yeah,I forgot that One,i will do.One more question  if i write a state as [q0,q1] is this same as [q1,q0].Actually this is also a confusion as the result of the video i had mentioned.

Comment: @techno: Yes, they’re the same. In the usual construction they’re actually **sets** of states from the NFA, so you’d write $\{q_0,q_1\}$, not $[q_0,q_1]$; and $\{q_0,q_1\}$ and $\{q_1,q_0\}$ are the same sets, since they have exactly the same elements.

Comment: Thank You very Much :) I now get a better idea

Comment: @techno: Excellent. You’re very welcome!